# Is there a way to return zero vs. an empty string when using the SUM function in snowflake?

Tags: sql, string, sum, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What would be the best way to display zero (0) or null vs. empty when using the sum function in snowflake/sql? For instance, I'm getting an empty string when sum equals zero when doing the following: `sum(case when t.Status='Done' then 1 end)` What am I missing?

Comment: add an ```else 0```

Comment: Can you share the whole statement? When I test, it returns null. For example: select sum(case when Status='Done' then 1 end) from values ('None') tmp(status);

Comment: thanks, added else, and still getting an empty string when sum equals zero. Query looks like: SELECT
  left(t.date_task) as date,
  left(DATE_TRUNC('week', t.date_task,10) as week_start,
  sum(case when t.status='Done' then 1 else 0 end) as task_status 
GROUP BY 1,2

Comment: Where is your empty string appearing?  It can't be appearing in your SUM.  And per your comment down below in the answer, Snowflake (and just about every other database I've ever used) treat NULL and empty string as different values.  You could use a NULLIF() function, if you want to return a NULL instead of an empty string, but not sure where you are seeing it based on your comment above.  Also, recommend you edit your original post with this extra information, so its clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everybody else has noted, Snowflake sum gives ether NULL or a , and it works correctly.

```
select 
    sum(case when Status='Done' then 1 end) as this_is_null
    ,sum(case when Status='Done' then 1 else 0 end) as this_is_zero
    ,sum(case when Status='None' then 1 else 0 end) as this_is_one
    ,sum(iff(status='Done', 1, 0)) as this_is_also_zero
from values ('None') tmp(status);
```

giving:

```
THIS_IS_NULL   THIS_IS_ZERO   THIS_IS_ONE   THIS_IS_ALSO_ZERO
<null>         0              1             0
```

so if you are getting an empty string, as your output it is because you are using the output of SUM to do string manipulation, and have something wrong.

Taking your example from your comment, and expanding it to make sense...

```
SELECT left(t.date_task,4) as date
    ,left(DATE_TRUNC('week', t.date_task),10) as week_start
    ,sum(case when t.status='Done' then 1 else 0 end) as task_status
FROM ( 
    select to_timestamp_ntz(date_task) as date_task, status 
    from values ('2020-05-05', 'Done'),('2020-04-05', 'None') v(date_task, status)
) t
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

gives what seems like correct results:

```
DATE    WEEK_START  TASK_STATUS
2020    2020-05-04  1
2020    2020-03-30  0
```

Comment: Thank you @Simeon. I also tried `cast(sum(case when t.Status='Done' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar)` to convert the expression. This method also worked on my end to display zero instead of empty when sum equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use `coalesce()`, the simplest method is an `else` clause:

```
sum(case when t.Status = 'Done' then 1 else 0 end)
```

SQL now supports an alternative syntax:

```
count(*) filter (where t.Status = 'Done')
```

However, Snowflake does not (yet) support this.

Comment: Thank you, tried both methods, and I'm still getting an empty string. It seems that an empty string in Snowflake is not equal to NULL; therefore coalesce don't work

Comment: @Alejandra . . . I don't understand.  This returns a number, not a string.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thank you for your help. Solved my question with the following: `cast(sum(case when t.Status='Done' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar)` to return zero vs. empty when sum equals zero.